# What is the function called 'numberOfLines'?

Tags: react-native

I modified numberOfLines in this code.
But I didn't figure out yet what hability it has.
What is this?

```
   <Text numberOfLines={10}>{this.state.bodyText}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numberOfLines` is used to limit visible text on screen.

From docs: (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines)

```
Used to truncate the text with an ellipsis after computing the text layout, including line wrapping, such that the total number of lines does not exceed this number.

This prop is commonly used with ellipsizeMode.
```